# Manifest merger failed while adding FirebaseUI library

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

My app is targeting sdk 25, with minSdk 14, compiledSdk 25and buildToolsVersion 25.0.0

When I try to add following dependency,

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

It gives: following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processGoogleDebugManifest'.

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
when I checked logs of AndroidManifest error:
It shows: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library
and suggest me to add Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.customtabs" to force usage.
```

when I am adding this, it gives various manifest merger errors.
And while finding the solution, someone suggested to chage sdk version to 26, but it also give various error.

I'm just beginner in this, so please help me out.

Comment: Post your gradle file.

Comment: try adding    maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        } to repositories

Comment: @ItzikSamara I already added that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted says it all:

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15

Change your minSdkVersion to 15 in order to use firebase-ui libraries.

Comment: as I mentioned, I can't change my minSdkversion. I asked about any other way.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question.  You can't change the minimum API requirements for a library.

Answer (score 0):

As you can [check here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/build.gradle) the Firebase UI-AUTH has a dependency with:

```
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1"
```

Here you can find the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#custom-tabs) and you can check the same in the Manifest inside the library:

> This package requires **API level 15** or higher.

**You can't change the minSdk required for a library** and you can't have a `minSdk = 14` if you use this library.

I read that it is not a option for you, but currently the minSdk=15 covers over the 99% of the distribution.
Here the updated distribution:
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html